# How to express window frame in SQL window function relating to property value of current row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, window-functions

Consider a table of events of form: `id,price,timestamp`. For each event I'd like to get the `min(price)` of all events that happen between `[curEvent.timestamp, curEvent.timestamp + 10sec]`

It seems SQL window functions would be a logical candidate.

For example, if I was sure how many events after the current event I want to inspect to calculate the `min(price)` this would be done with something like this:

```
SELECT *,min(price) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 100 FOLLOWING) AS min_price from events
```

However, I don't know the number of events/rows up front. Instead, I want it to be variable based on `[curEvent.timestamp, curEvent.timestamp + 10sec]`

It this at all possible?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this with a window function, but you could use a corrolated subquery instead:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT MIN(price)
        FROM   events
        WHERE  ts BETWEEN e.ts AND e.ts + INTERVAL '10 SECOND')
FROM   events e
```

Comment: This would not work because this `WHERE` clause with `<=` comparison also looks into the past which is not wanted. You should change it into `WHERE  ts BETWEEN e.ts AND e.ts + INTERVAL '10 SECOND'` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c787aa971969dae812b989e97b9c2d50

Comment: @S-Man nice catch! Edited in there.

Comment: Nice solution anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**PostgreSQL 11 solution**:

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=77408eca0ba72184c20fd13b3504146e)

```
SELECT
    price, 
    ts,
    min(price) OVER (ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '10 seconds' FOLLOWING)
FROM times
```

Postgres 11 adds the functionality of `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL`s for window functions which does exactly what you expect ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)):

**Sample data** (first 2 columns) and **result** (3rd column):

```
price   ts                      min
1       2018-09-09 10:00:00     1
2       2018-09-09 10:00:04     2
100     2018-09-09 10:00:09.8   10
200     2018-09-09 10:00:10     3.5
20      2018-09-09 10:00:11     3.5
10      2018-09-09 10:00:19     3.5
3.5     2018-09-09 10:00:20     3.5
35      2018-09-09 10:00:21     35
```

[Further reading, JOOQ Blog](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/07/05/postgresql-11s-support-for-sql-standard-groups-and-exclude-window-function-clauses/)

Comment: Ah that's awesome. Had already accepted the other answer, but this looks even nicer. Will try soon.